# mvc actionlink parameters change route url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-routing

so i have an actionlink line on my action

```
<% foreach ( var item in Model) { %>
   <% Html.ActionLink (item.Name, "Profile", new { id = item.Id } )%>
<% } %>
```

it produces this URL, (if item.Id is 1):

```
http://localhost:1111/company/profile/1
```

is it possible to produce the url/route as (basically using item.Name instead of the Id:

```
http://localhost:1111/company/profile/nameofcompany1
```

wasn't really sure how to handle to handle the routing of this..if i should change the routing on the global.asax for the controller.

thoughts are welcome.

Thanks!

-G

Comment: Are you looking to get a link like stackoverflow's links, i.e., `http://localhost:1111/company/profile/1/mycompanyname`?  If so, then a different solution is called for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure:

```
<% Html.ActionLink (item.Name, "Profile", new { name = item.Name } )%>
```

Now of course this assumes that you modify your route definitions and replace the `id` token by `name` and also replace the `id` action parameter in your controller actions by `name`.

This being said, the usefulness of such urls seems pretty limited to me. What if you have 2 items with the same name? I would recommend you always using ids in order to identify your items in an unique manner. And if you want to much to have some name in this url, take for example how urls are implemented on StackOverflow: they use question id, and append a slug (not the name, it's a filtered name because things can quickly get out of control if your names contain some special characters) at the end of the url.

Comment: i try to avoid the item.Name for the same reasons you stated (duplicate names and special chars) and yeah that's where i'm going at. i was thinking stick with the id then append a slug on the routing to display the name. was just wondering if there's a way where i can use the id to generate the url but will display the name instead. i guess im making it too complicated to make too easy for the user..